# wildfly 14 : Services with missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: postgresql, eclipselink, wildfly, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I am new to wildfly and jpa.

I'm used eclipselink version 2.7.3 for library

this is my [link](https://files.fm/u/juxwn3yh) for POM, persistence, and standalone files

when I deploying my ear file's I'm getting this error:

```
{
   "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" =>   ["jboss.naming.context.java.app.EnterpriseSPIN-ear.jdbc.digisign_db"],
  "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"EnterpriseSPIN-ear.ear#digisignPU\" is missing    [jboss.naming.context.java.app.EnterpriseSPIN-ear.jdbc.digisign_db]"]
}
```

**my persistence xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="digisignPU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/digisign</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="PostgreSQL"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="someuser"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="somepassword"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.182.7:5432/digisign_db"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my **standalone xml**

```
<datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/digisign" pool-name="digisign" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.182.7:5432/digisign_db</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>someuser</user-name>
                    <password>somepassword</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

**this my postgresql module xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.2.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

and **this my eclipselink persistence module xml**

```
<module name="org.eclipse.persistence" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="public"/>
</properties>

<resources>
    <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-14.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar">
     <filter>
            <exclude path="javax/**"/>
    </filter>
    </resource-root>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="asm.asm"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    <module name="org.antlr"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried it many times but I've been unsuccessful. Please help!

Comment: Can you first try to test the connection: `/subsystem=datasources/data-source=digisign:test-connection-in-pool()`. Or test it in the Web Admin Console. Also where is your `persistence.xml` located?

Comment: I try  to connection using the admin console, the result "Successfully tested the connection for the data source to be created". my persistence.xml is located in ejb.jar

Comment: try to remove the `eclipselink.jdbc.*` properties in `persistence.xml` they are defined in the datasource which is referenced by `jta-data-source`

Comment: I did it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of interrest i created a small [example](https://github.com/hwirnsberger/eclipselink_wildfly). (It is just a quick hack :-)

It is working on wildfly 14 with databases h2 and postgres. Try to compare this example with your application.

I also had a look at your [pom.xml](https://files.fm/u/juxwn3yh). There are dependencies which should be set to scope provided. Try to set `eclipselink` and `postgres` dependencies to provided. They should not be added to your `ear`. They are provided from wildfly.

Comment: great! :-D what was the problem? how did you fix it?

Comment: the problem is in my pom. I deleted depencies and  try to set eclipselink and dependecies provided from wildfly. 

Answer (score 0):

I have a working project (running under Wildfly) for which I did not have to include the "java:" prefix in the datasource defined in persistence.xml :

**In standalone.xml**

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/xxx">
```

**In persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1" ...>
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" >
        ...
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/xxx</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: this my link persistence, pom, and standalone file https://files.fm/u/juxwn3yh. can you help me to check it